# MongoError: bad auth Authentication failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dotenv

```
const uri=`mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@cluster0.crceb.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
```

*When I run the code I am getting the following error*

**"MongoError: bad auth Authentication failed."**

Any ideas that's mean?

Comment: Do you have those two environment variables set: DB_USER and DB_PASS?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Answer (score 0):

Check the env file correctly. And add project name too. If not, then change the password so that if it includes a number, write just a letter.
You can try another world inside of DB_USER

check your env data in console.log and consider it with your env file